# Wpf c# ticker rss news reader

Tags: c#, wpf, ticker, news-ticker

I'm making an application for wpf C# in expression blend 4. I have followed RumorMills tutorial over at http://www.jarloo.com/rumormill4/

However he doesn't provide a full tutorial, so i have taken som of his code trying to implement it into my own "home media center" application for testing. I have sorted out 90% of the errors, just one remaining - i hope it doesn't come any additional ones... You could find any additional code not included in the question over at his post. See my code below:

Main code file for the screen hosting the news ticker

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using Microsoft.Expression.Controls;
using MySoftware_Inspire.Feed;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace blablabla
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<string> weatherwords = new List<string> {"weather", "in", "umbrella", "rain", "sun", "sunny", "overcast", "forecast", "cloudy"};
    List<string> mathwords = new List<string> {"+", "-", "*", "/", ":"};
    String searchInput;
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;

    private readonly FeedManager manager = new FeedManager();
    private readonly Ticker<TickerItem> ticker;

    private delegate void FeedDelegate(FeedItem itm);

    //would be better to detect the height of the titlebar 
    //and window chrome instead of hardcoding this.
    private const int FULL_HEIGHT = 75;
    private const int SHORT_HEIGHT = 55;

    private int height = FULL_HEIGHT;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;

        ticker = new Ticker<TickerItem>(LayoutRoot) {Speed = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)};
        ticker.ItemDisplayed += ticker_ItemDisplayed;

        manager.NewFeedItem += manager_NewFeedItem;

        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    }

            private void ticker_ItemDisplayed(object sender, ItemEventArgs<TickerItem> e)
    {
        txtItems.Text = ticker.Items.Count.ToString();

        manager.MarkFeedAsRead(e.Item.FeedItem);
    }

    private void manager_NewFeedItem(object sender, ItemEventArgs<FeedItem> e)
    {
        //Got a new article. Marshall to the UI thread
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new FeedDelegate(AddItem), e.Item);
    }

    private void AddItem(FeedItem itm)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            ticker.Items.Enqueue(new TickerItem(itm));
            txtItems.Text = ticker.Items.Count.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void homequicktip_DoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Doubleclicked to homequicktip notification
        DoubleAnimation fadeouthomequicktip = new DoubleAnimation();
        fadeouthomequicktip.From = 1;
        fadeouthomequicktip.To = 0.0;
        fadeouthomequicktip.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        //Play fade out animation on homequicktip
        homequicktip.BeginAnimation(Callout.OpacityProperty, fadeouthomequicktip);
    }

    private void MainWindow_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Start feed manager
        manager.Start();

        //Load up clock and play startup animations
        dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();

        //Rotate arcs for nice effect

        //Arc 1 rotation
        DoubleAnimation arcrotateAnim1 = new DoubleAnimation();
        arcrotateAnim1.From = -70;
        arcrotateAnim1.To = -3600;
        arcrotateAnim1.AutoReverse = true;
        arcrotateAnim1.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        arcrotateAnim1.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        arc1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
        arc1.RenderTransform = rt;
        rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, arcrotateAnim1);

        //Arc 2 rotation
        DoubleAnimation arcrotateAnim2 = new DoubleAnimation();
        arcrotateAnim2.From = 90;
        arcrotateAnim2.To = 3690;
        arcrotateAnim2.AutoReverse = true;
        arcrotateAnim2.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        arcrotateAnim2.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        arc1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        RotateTransform rt2 = new RotateTransform();
        arc2.RenderTransform = rt2;
        rt2.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, arcrotateAnim2);
    }
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        manager.Stop();
        manager.SaveReadFeeds();
    }

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HeightChanged)
        {
            if (e.NewSize.Height != height) Height = height;
        }
    }

    private void btnLock_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowStyle == WindowStyle.None)
        {
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
            height = FULL_HEIGHT;
            Height = height;
        }
        else
        {
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            height = SHORT_HEIGHT;
            Height = height;
        }
    }

    private void btnStop_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btnStop.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        btnGo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        ticker.Stop();
    }

    private void btnGo_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        btnStop.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        btnGo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        ticker.Start();
    }
        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Updating clock
            timeLabel.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        private void searchTextbox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
            {
            //Enter key was pressed - begin search

            //Create instance of SearchWindow
            SearchWindow SearchWindow = new SearchWindow();

            //Memorize current text in TextBox so it doesn't look like we've changed anything
            searchInput = searchTextBox.Text;

            //Pressed enter on searchTextBox
            if (searchTextBox.Text.Contains(" "))
            {
                //Search input contains spaces which needs to be removed before search can happen
                searchTextBox.Text.Replace(" ", "+");
            }

            //Open search
            SearchWindow.searchBrowser.Navigate("http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=" + searchTextBox.Text);
            SearchWindow.Show();
            }
        }
}
}
```

TickerItem.xaml:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="Jarloo.RumorMill4.TickerItem"
x:Name="UserControl"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" Height="39">

<Grid Height="39" >
    <TextBlock x:Name="PART_TextBlock" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="NoWrap">
        <Hyperlink x:Name="hlLink" RequestNavigate="hpLink_RequestNavigate">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitle" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" TextWrapping="NoWrap"></TextBlock>
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtDate" Margin="0,12,0,1" Foreground="#FF939393" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontSize="10"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtSource" Margin="0,20,0,1" Foreground="#FFD47432" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontSize="10" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

TickerItem.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using blablablabla.Feed;

namespace blablablabla
{
public partial class TickerItem
{
    public TickerItem(FeedItem item)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FeedItem = item;

        txtDate.Text = item.PubDate;
        txtTitle.Text = item.Title;

        if (item.Link.ToLower().StartsWith("http"))
        {
            try
            {
                hlLink.NavigateUri = new Uri(item.Link);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        txtSource.Text = item.Source;
    }

    public FeedItem FeedItem { get; private set;}

    public string PubDate
    {
        get
        {
            TextBlock date = (TextBlock)FindName("txtDate");
            return date.Text;
        }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return txtTitle.Text;
        }
    }

    public string Url
    {
        get
        {
            return hlLink.NavigateUri.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string Source
    {
        get
        {
            return txtSource.Text;
        }
    }

    private void hpLink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.ToString()));
    }
}
}
```

Ticker.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace blablablabla
{
public class Ticker<T> where T : FrameworkElement
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer displayTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public EventHandler<ItemEventArgs<T>> ItemDisplayed;

    public bool Running { get; set; }
    public double SeperatorSize { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Speed { get; set; }
    public Queue<T> Items { get; set; }
    public Panel Container { get; private set; }

    public void Stop()
    {
        displayTimer.Stop();
        Running = false;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        displayTimer.Start();
        displayTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1);
        Running = true;
    }

    public Ticker(Panel container)
    {
        SeperatorSize = 25;

        Container = container;

        Container.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        Container.Arrange(new Rect(Container.DesiredSize));

        Speed = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 40);

        Items = new Queue<T>();

        displayTimer.Tick += displayTimer_Tick;
        displayTimer.Start();
        Running = true;
    }

    private void displayTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayNextItem();
    }

    private void DisplayNextItem()
    {
        if (Items.Count == 0) return;

        T item = Items.Dequeue();

        Container.Children.Add(item);

        AnimateMove(item);

        if (ItemDisplayed != null) ItemDisplayed(this, new ItemEventArgs<T>(item));
    }

    private void AnimateMove(FrameworkElement e)
    {
        const double to = -500;

        e.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        e.Arrange(new Rect(e.DesiredSize));

        double from = Container.ActualWidth;

        int unitsPerSec = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Abs(from - to)/Speed.TotalSeconds);
        int nextFire = Convert.ToInt32((e.ActualWidth + SeperatorSize)/unitsPerSec);

        displayTimer.Stop();
        displayTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, nextFire);
        displayTimer.Start();

        TaggedDoubleAnimation ani = new TaggedDoubleAnimation
                                        {
                                            From = from, 
                                            To = to, 
                                            Duration = new Duration(Speed), 
                                            TargetElement = e
                                        };

        ani.Completed += ani_Completed;

        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        e.RenderTransform = trans;

        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, ani, HandoffBehavior.Compose);
    }

    private void ani_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clock clock = (Clock) sender;
        TaggedDoubleAnimation ani = (TaggedDoubleAnimation) clock.Timeline;

        FrameworkElement element = ani.TargetElement;
        Container.Children.Remove(element);
    }
}
}
```

The error is as follows - it may not be 100% properly translated because i'm norwegian and the error was printed out in norwegian. Have a look:

Error:

The type blablablabla.TickerItem cannot be used as the type parameter T in the generic type or method blablablabla.Ticker. It does not exist any implicit reference-convertion from blablablabla.TickerItem to System.Windows.FrameworkElement

Do any of you guys know what this means?

I'm REALLY stuck here, please help! Thanks!

Comment: On which line are you getting this error?

Comment: Line 29, on the newly added code file, check the code now. This line: private readonly Ticker<TickerItem> ticker;

Comment: Could you try including the full namespace? It's possible that it's mixing up references. Normally this should work

Comment: like this u mean: private readonly blablabla.Ticker<TickerItem> ticker; ??? Still doesn't work

Comment: Like this: MySoftware_Inspire.Ticker<MySoftware_Inspire.TickerItem> With each class with its own ns

Comment: nope, still doesn't work

Comment: Is TickerItem a UserControl, a page or something else?

Comment: It's the complete "thing" that displays the feeds, all of the ui stuff the ticker rss reader uses visually. The xaml for that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29132/discussion-between-kenneth-and-user1446632)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your XAML:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="Jarloo.RumorMill4.TickerItem"
    x:Name="UserControl"
    d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" Height="39">
```

The attribute `x:Class` should have the following value:

```
MySoftware_Inspire.TickerItem
```

You probably forgot to change this after following the tutorial

Comment: Hi again, so the app is starting, all the other functions are normal. But it doesn't display any feeds, any ideas? How does the copy i sent you behave?